# Handler for checking radio button based on another input field stops working after unchecking radio button from another handler

Tags: jquery, radio-button, jquery-events, prop

I have a form with a radio button and a text input field:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar">
<input id="baz" type="text">
...
```

The text input field has a `keyup` handler associated with it that will check the radio button when I start typing in the text input field:

```
$('#baz').on('keyup', function() {
  var bar = $('input[name="foo"][value="bar"]');
  if (!bar.is(':checked')) {
    bar.prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

The form also has a "Reset" button (with an `id` of `reset`) and the following `click` handler:

```
$('#reset').on('click', function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
  $('input').val('');
});
```

**The problem**: The `keyup` handler for the input field stops working after clicking the "Reset" button.

When I augment the handler with calls to `console.log` like this:

```
$('#baz').on('keyup', function() {
  var bar = $('input[name="foo"][value="bar"]');
  if (!bar.is(':checked')) {
    console.log('not checked');
    bar.prop('checked', true);
    console.log('New value for "checked" property: ' + bar.prop('checked'));
  } else {
    console.log('checked');
  }
});
```

I get the following output when I enter two characters *before* clicking the "Reset" button:

> not checked
>
> New value for "checked" property: true"
>
> checked

When entering two characters *after* clicking the "Reset" button, the output looks like this:

> not checked
>
> New value for "checked" property: undefined
>
> not checked
>
> New value for "checked" property: undefined

The `checked` property of the radio button is now `undefined` instead of `false`. (I am assuming that that is the reason why the `keyup` handler can't set it anymore?)

I'd like to understand what's going on here. How do I need to modify my code to keep the functionality of the `keyup` handler after clicking "Reset"?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but so far I haven't been able to dig up a solution for this problem on here or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `#reset` event handler you're setting the `value` of all input elements to `''`.

In your `keyup` handler you're selecting the radio button using its `name` and `value`:

```
var bar = $('input[name="foo"][value="bar"]');
```

Which selects nothing, because you no longer have `input[value="bar"]`